# Prevent refresh token from being used to renew access token after session ends

Tags: session, azure-ad-b2c, access-token, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, refresh-token

We've got the following settings configured, based off instructions found at MSFT [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-custom-policy):

- Access token lifetime: 60 minutes
- Refresh token lifetime: 24 hours
- Refresh token sliding window lifetime: 24 hours
- Session lifetime: 30 minutes

Within our application, we test the access token lifetime on each page load and, if it is going to expire in the next five minutes and the refresh token hasn't expired, we use the refresh token to ask Azure AD B2C for a new access token.

The problem is that even though the session lifetime is set to 30 minutes, the refresh token still returns a valid access token when it is used. Further, the minimum value for the refresh token is 24 hours.

Is there any way to prevent the refresh token from being used if the session has expired? If we ignore the actual refresh token from Azure AD B2C and change the access token lifespan to 30 minutes, and use that to essentially force the user to be logged out once the 30 minutes expires, would there still be some way for a malicious third-party to use tools like Fiddler to grab the access/refresh tokens Azure AD B2C returns, and use them to keep the user's session active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even the **session ends**, you can still renew **access token** with the help of refresh token as its lifetime is minimum 24 hrs. To prevent that, you can call [**invalidateAllRefreshTokens**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-invalidateallrefreshtokens?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) graph query once the session ends.

I registered one B2C application and added **API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now, I generated tokens using **authorization code** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
scope: https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/xxxx/api.test openid offline_access
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

Using the above  **refresh token**, I'm able to generate access token successfully like below:

```http
POST https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:refresh_token
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret
scope: https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/xxxx/api.test
refresh_token:<paste_refresh_token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

To prevent refresh token from being used to renew access token, I ran below query in [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) for revoking refresh tokens:

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<user_id>/invalidateAllRefreshTokens
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I tried to renew access token with same refresh token after few minutes, I got error saying **token is revoked** like below:

```http
POST https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:refresh_token
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret
scope: https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/xxxx/api.test
refresh_token:<paste_refresh_token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[authentication - Cannot make Azure B2C refersh token become invalid - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73802183/cannot-make-azure-b2c-refersh-token-become-invalid/73804973#73804973) by **me.**

Comment: Hm. So, essentially, I would need to have a table that logs user sessions, and then a job which would run every night to invalidate them? Feels very heavy-handed. There's no setting over on Azure that would allow me to automatically invalidate the refresh token when the session expires?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such option in Azure Portal to automatically invalidate refresh tokens. Alternatively, you can also run this PowerShell command: `Invoke-MgBetaInvalidateUserRefreshToken -UserId $userId`

Comment: Hmmmm. Okay. So, then, do you happen to know the answer to the second part of my question? Is there any security risk associated with having an active refresh token?

Comment: Yes, there are security risks as refresh tokens can be used to obtain new access and refresh token pairs when the current access token expires. With this, anyone can access resources without any authentication that leads to unauthorized access.